# PulseAudio Remote Control on Android

Tags: pulseaudio

What I'm looking for is a way to control pulseaudio from my phone.

I love Pulseaudio Volume Control (the desktop app which lets you control each application's volume level). The best thing would be an android app which connects to pavu. I guess that's not going to happen anytime soon, so this is why I'm asking for alternatives here.

What I've been thinking of but haven't done because it's so clumsy:

- connect to my computer via vnc as a second screen and have pavucontrol run there
  --> not really elegant at all
- write my own android app and have it log in to my pc using ssh.
  --> well, this takes time. Last resort.

---

Remote controlling only my music player for example is NOT an option. I have many applications running which play sound and I want to mix them all together, not with an app for each one of these. I'm talking about

- being on teamspeak
- playing some music
- having system sounds
- and the occasional notification from somewhere

at the same time. Doing it manually is just not an option.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Been looking for the same sort of thing for the past few days. With only minor difficulties I was able to build [reverb](https://github.com/hchapman/reverb) and get it working. I was able to control my laptop's pulseaudio after loading module-native-protocol-tcp. Next step is forwarding port 4713 from my router to my desktop so I can control that too.

The project hasn't been updated in about a year, and doesn't yet allow cookie authentication, so I might have to resurrect it.

Comment: awesome, you're the best. I'll try that instantly and maybe push some code in your direction once I have the time